# The space of continuous functions $C([0,1])$ is not complete in the $L^2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inner-products, lp-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to prove that under the $L^2$ norm,  $C([0,1])$ does not give rise to a  complete metric space. To do this I am trying to find a Cauchy Sequence which does not converge in $C([0,1])$. As a template (on $C([a,b])$) I am led to believe the following is Cauchy:

$$f_n (x) = \begin{cases} 
1 &\mbox{if } 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\ 
1 - 2n(x-\frac{1}{2}) & \mbox{if } \frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2}\\
0 & \mbox{if } \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1
 \end{cases}  $$

But I am struggling to show this is Cauchy, I have tried integrating from 0 to 1 but this is giving a very nasty integral and I was wondering if anyone has a better method?

Comment: what is the Euclidean Norm/inner product on $C([0,1])$? You mean the $L^1$-norm?

Comment: Hint: Let say $m>n$, then $f_m$ and $f_n$ differs on a small set (What is that set?)

Comment: Sorry (mod 2) came from the latex template I was using. And I mean $L^2$, is this not the Euclidean norm? I will edit the above if so thank you

Comment: You can make things easy and approximate $\Vert f_n- f_m\Vert_2^2\le 4\cdot |1/(2n)-1/(2m)|$. (Note $f_n-f_m$ is $0$ of the interval with endpoints $1/(2n)+1/2$ and $1/(2m)+1/2$.)

Comment: Great thanks David got it!

Comment: @DavidMitra, can you please elaborate on this inequality?

Answer (score 3):

You can make things easy and approximate $$\Vert f_n- f_m\Vert_2^2\le 4\cdot |1/(2n)-1/(2m)|$$  Note $f_n-f_m$ is $0$ of the interval with endpoints $1/(2n)+1/2$ and $1/(2m)+1/2$.

-- [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703973/the-space-of-continuous-functions-c0-1-is-not-complete-in-the-l2-norm#comment1474364_703973)